# How can I remove a line-feed/newline BEFORE a pattern using sed

Tags: sed, awk

The title already states it:

I want to use some linux one liner (e.g. sed)

to transform

```
Anytext
{
```

into

```
Anytext{
```

Can this be done using sed or if not with sed then with an awk one liner ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure,

```
sed 'N;s/\n{/{/'
```

Or a more thorough version:

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n{/{/g'
```

Here, `:r` sets a label that we can refer to in order to create a loop;

`$!{...}` executes the given set of commands for every line except the last one;

`N;br` are two commands the get executed in the loop: `N` appends a new line to the pattern space, and `br` branches back to the label `r`, completing the loop.

Then you have all of your file in pattern space when you run the final command:

```
s/\n{/{/g
```

You can see the difference between the two approaches if you try it on something like

```
Anytext
{
{
{
```

Comment: First one was just sufficient, I was modifying c++ function definitions to, so this is fine

Comment: @Martin `N` appends one more line to the pattern space, so that there are two lines separated with `\n` in the pattern space. See `man sed` for a list of commands or [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for a more extensive reference.

Comment: Very good second match. An explanation would be nice. The second option is really useful if you have multiple successive lines of which you want to remove the newlines.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum Thanks. I've added a brief explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -ne '$! N; /^.*\n{/ { s/\n//; p; b }; $ { p; q }; P; D' infile
```

A test. Assuming `infile` with content:

```
one
Anytext
{
two
three
{
four
five
{
```

Output will be:

```
one
Anytext{
two
three{
four
five{
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to remove the newline from a `\n{` sequence `bbe` seems to be the simplest tool to use:

```
bbe -e 's/\n{/{/' infile
```

Comment: Never heard of bbe before, it doesn't seem to be part of the standard distribution (at least under Ubuntu) and requires a separate download. Looks useful though.

Comment: It's been part of Debian for a while and lives at [SourceForge](http://sf.net/projects/bbe-). I've found use for it a couple of times, e.g. finding markers in a binary stream and saving the data between them.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/.*\n{/ba};s/\n{/{/g;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
cat file
one
Anytext
{
two
three
{
four
five
{
```

```
awk '{printf (!/^{/&&NR>1?RS:x)"%s",$0} END {print ""}' file
one
Anytext{
two
three{
four
five{
```